# Reading problems from property file (Spaces)

Tags: java, html, jsp, internationalization, struts

I use i18n in my web app. Reading it from .properties.
Everything ok, but when I'm reading text for button (type="submit"), it's reading before first space only.

Code from jsp file:

```
<input type="submit" value=<fmt:message key="button.ok" /> style="width:100"/>
```

Code from .properties file:

```
button.ok=Sign in
```

But, when I'm reading the text from property to other text fields (not buttons) - everything works good.
for ex.

```
<fmt:message key="login.password" />
```

And
     login.password=Enter your password:

P.S. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it like

```
<input type="submit" value="<fmt:message key='button.ok'/>" style="width:100"/>
```